# IBM Form Experience Builder Service Call

Tags: forms

I am new to IBM Form Experience Builder.

I want to populate data dynamically in drop down, say I have some values in database and I want drop down to have those values.

I found that there is a Service concept, but don't know how to create service and how to use it.

Please let me know if any link or document available to do that

Appreciate your help
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can populate the options in your drop down  via a search service.

If the values you need are in another Forms Experience Builder (FEB) app this is easy since each FEB app automatically exposes itself as a service to any other FEB app  (provided security settings on the app allow so). Go into the properties settings for the dropdown and on the second tab you will see options to populating via a service.  Select this and then specify the search service for FEB source you want to pull values from.

If the values are in another system or db you will need to setup a service definition.  Documentation for setting this up can be found [here](http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lfwiki.nsf/dx/Creating_a_Custom_Transport_and_Service_Description).